# How can I count characters and lines while I am typing on a Memo

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

I wrote the following code to count lines and characters while the user is typing. But it has a problem, it starts to count after the user enters the first character and when he presses backspace it increases the counter and then starts to decrease it.

```
procedure TForm1.Memo1KeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; var KeyChar: Char;
  Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  Text1.Text := 'Lines: ' + IntToStr (Memo1.Lines.Count);
  Text2.Text := 'Characters: ' + IntToStr (Length(Memo1.Text));
end;
```

Comment: Do it from the `OnChange` event.

Comment: When i do it on the OnChange event it doesn't update except when i press enter.

Comment: If your aim is to always show the current line and char count and if this would be a VCL project (what I thought at the first time), you'd also need to handle the situation when the user pastes the text by using the popup menu, because that will change the memo text without any key press. For mobile platforms I don't know if you need to care about it though.

Comment: Yes, i want to count the characters even if the text has pasted and not typed, so i suppose the best solution is to write my code on the OnChangeTracking event. Thanks very much TLama.

Answer (score 6):

Write a handler for the [`OnChangeTracking`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/FMX.Memo.TMemo.OnChangeTracking) event. The first time I left my comment here I missed you're writing an FMX application, hence my suggestion to use the `OnChange` event was wrong. You could use it in the VCL project, but in FMX the [`OnChange`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/FMX.Memo.TMemo.OnChange) has a different meaning.

The reference for the [`OnChangeTracking`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/FMX.Memo.TMemo.OnChangeTracking) states:

> Occurs when the text in the memo control is modified. Write an
>   OnChangeTracking event handler to respond immediately to any changes
>   made to the text in the memo control. The Text property of the memo
>   control will already be updated to reflect any changes. This event
>   provides the first opportunity to respond to modifications that the
>   user makes by typing into the memo control.
>
> The difference between OnChangeTracking and OnChange is that
>   OnChangeTracking occurs at each modification of text in the memo
>   control.

So, if you move your code to the [`OnChangeTracking`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/FMX.Memo.TMemo.OnChangeTracking) event handler, you should got it to work:

```
procedure TForm1.Memo1ChangeTracking(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Text1.Text := 'Lines: ' + IntToStr (Memo1.Lines.Count);
  Text2.Text := 'Characters: ' + IntToStr (Length(Memo1.Text));
end;
```

Comment: For large content, evaluating character count is going to hurt.

Comment: @David, I don't know how it's implemented in FMX.

Comment: It's the same TStrings

Comment: This does indeed become unusable for large amounts of text. But I'm not convinced FMX TMemo can handle large amounts of text anyway!! Not that I know how to do it better.

Comment: @David, as I said. I don't know how it's implemented in XE5 FMX. I don't know what OP is working on, so let's just hope it's not going to be an editor for hundreds of thousands of chars (on mobile phones such editor would be a bit unfriendly). However, the main point is the event here ;-)

Answer (score -1):

```
Text1.Text := 'Lines: ' + Memo1.Lines.Count.ToString;
Text2.Text := 'Characters: ' + Memo1.Lines.Text.Length.ToString;
```